# GB cart with Ram, Rom, no MBC. How do they work?

Tags: memory

Gameboy cartridges, without memory banking, have 32KB of ROM and no RAM. To have more, carts *tend* to use a MBC (Memory Bank Controller) IC to add RAM and ROM, among other things.

However, two cartridge types, 8 & 9 ([08h  ROM+RAM 09h ROM+RAM+BATTERY](http://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/The_Cartridge_Header#0147_-_Cartridge_Type)) don't *seem* to have an MBC.

How do types 8 & 9 work?

Comment: `Small games of not more than 32KBytes ROM do not require a MBC chip for ROM banking. The ROM is directly mapped to memory at 0000-7FFFh. Optionally up to 8KByte of RAM could be connected at A000-BFFF, even though that could require a tiny MBC-like circuit, but no real MBC chip.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cart connector has a pin (which seems to be variously reffered to as "MREQ" or CS_SRAM) which distinguishes between access to the cart rom space and access to the cart ram space. I'm seeing conflicting information on line about the active polirity of this line so it may be nessacery to do some testing.

If you can find a rom and ram chip with the right chip select polarities you may just be able to hook them up directly. If the chip select polarities on your chips are wrong you may need an inverter. Definately no need for anything as complex as a memory bank controller just to have both rom and ram.